# Building Qt from source, qmake is invoke by their script with invalid parameters?

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to get a boot2qt build environment setup.  It's for an iMX53 - not that it should really matter when it comes to answering my question...

So, as part of the process I run their script called "build_qt.sh".  That calls a nested configure script with a big pile of parameters.  That script, in turn, builds qmake from source, and then tries to use the new qmake to build the rest of qt (from what it looks like?).

After a long battle, I got it to successfully create the qmake binary, but then the script ends by invoking that with all the parameters passed to the configure script.  Qmake then fails because most of these parameters are not valid qmake options!

Here's an excerpt from build_qt.sh:

```
CONFIGURE_ARGS="${CONFIGURE_ARGS} \
                -commercial -confirm-license -release \
                -device ${DEVICE} \
        -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=${WORKDIR}/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/${COMPILER} \
                -sysroot ${WORKDIR}/toolchain/sysroots/${SYSROOT} \
                -no-xcb -separate-debug-info -silent -nomake examples -nomake tests -tslib -no-pch -v"

...

./configure ${CONFIGURE_ARGS}
```

At the end of the that configure script, it does this:

```
"$outpath/bin/qmake" "$relpathMangled" -- "$@"
```

Note the `$@`.  That's where all those config arguments end up, which blows it up.  Specifically, it complains about the first argument it gets that isn't intended for qmake.

Here's the actual statement it tries to execute:

```
/home/osboxes/Qt/Boot2Qt-2.x/imx53qsb-eLinux/build-imx53qsb/bin/qmake /home/osboxes/Qt/Boot2Qt-2.x/imx53qsb-eLinux/build-imx53qsb/qt5-src -- -commercial -confirm-license -release -device linux-imx53qsb-hf-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/osboxes/Qt/Boot2Qt-2.x/imx53qsb-eLinux/build-imx53qsb/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi- -sysroot /home/osboxes/Qt/Boot2Qt-2.x/imx53qsb-eLinux/build-imx53qsb/toolchain/sysroots/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi -no-xcb -separate-debug-info -silent -nomake examples -nomake tests -tslib -no-pch -v
```

And this is the result:

```
ERROR: Unknown command line option '-commercial'.
```

Here is the actual qmake binary help output, which defines the expected syntax:

```
Usage: ./bin/qmake [mode] [options] [files]

QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project

Mode:
  -project       Put qmake into project file generation mode
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as files to
                 be built,
                 defaults to *; *; *; *.ts; *.xlf; *.qrc
                 Note: The created .pro file probably will 
                 need to be edited. For example add the QT variable to 
                 specify what modules are required.
  -makefile      Put qmake into makefile generation mode (default)
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as project files to
                 be processed, if skipped qmake will try to find a project
                 file in your current working directory

Warnings Options:
  -Wnone         Turn off all warnings; specific ones may be re-enabled by
                 later -W options
  -Wall          Turn on all warnings
  -Wparser       Turn on parser warnings
  -Wlogic        Turn on logic warnings (on by default)
  -Wdeprecated   Turn on deprecation warnings (on by default)

Options:
   * You can place any variable assignment in options and it will be *
   * processed as if it was in [files]. These assignments will be    *
   * processed before [files] by default.                            *
  -o file        Write output to file
  -d             Increase debug level
  -t templ       Overrides TEMPLATE as templ
  -tp prefix     Overrides TEMPLATE so that prefix is prefixed into the value
  -help          This help
  -v             Version information
  -early         All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right before default_pre.prf
  -before        All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right before [files] (the default)
  -after         All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed after [files]
  -late          All subsequent variable assignments will be
                 parsed right after default_post.prf
  -norecursive   Don't do a recursive search
  -recursive     Do a recursive search
  -set <prop> <value> Set persistent property
  -unset <prop>  Unset persistent property
  -query <prop>  Query persistent property. Show all if <prop> is empty.
  -qtconf file   Use file instead of looking for qt.conf
  -cache file    Use file as cache           [makefile mode only]
  -spec spec     Use spec as QMAKESPEC       [makefile mode only]
  -nocache       Don't use a cache file      [makefile mode only]
  -nodepend      Don't generate dependencies [makefile mode only]
  -nomoc         Don't generate moc targets  [makefile mode only]
  -nopwd         Don't look for files in pwd [project mode only]
```

Note that the parent `build_qt.sh` script runs Make after this.  Also, the qmake "default mode" is `-makefile` which will `Put qmake into makefile generation mode (default)`. So, I'm pretty certain this command that is failing to execute is supposed to be writing a makefile (essentially this is a "configure script" inside another one).

Does anyone know what that command should be here?

Could someone run a similar instance of `build_qt.sh` for me and post what command is run here by their functional script?  That would likely go a very long ways towards solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the parent `build_qt.sh` script and the `configure` script come from different versions of Qt.  They are not compatible!  Older versions of Qt don't have this troublesome line:

```
"$outpath/bin/qmake" "$relpathMangled" -- "$@"
```

Instead they look like this:

```
"$outpath/bin/qmake" "$relpathMangled"
```

Which makes way more sense!  I don't know why the current configure file has that funkiness in it, but it doesn't matter for me at the moment.